# API endpoint in Laravel hook

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to establish an API endpoint in a laravel voyager hook?

All the documentation I can find shows how to set up a listener for a web request, but these endpoints will not take a post.

Comment: Can you explain more? What exactly you want? Some code example maybe.

Comment: I don't really have a code example since I cannot find one. I did mean adding an API endpoint in a Voyager hook though.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the post route in your api routes file.

Example:

```php
// routes/api.php
<?php

Route::post('/webhooks', 'WebhooksController');
```

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/Api/WebhooksController

public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    // handle webhook
}
```

Then posting data to `yourapp.test/api/webhooks` should work.